# Cannot get form_state storage or protected form values to work

Tags: 8, forms

I am building a form using formBuilder. I have tried two methods to store values across form submit/validate for usage in ajax callbacks, but have been unsuccessful in either.

The first method, was to store a value in $form_state->set('name','value'); and retreiving it in the form submit/validate handler. That returned an empty result.

The second method was to store a variable on the class itself `protected $image_deltas = 0;` and then when the ajax form submit/validation is triggered, $this->image_deltas++; However, when I do this, it still does not work.

The following is the code I am using.

```php
$form['images'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#id' => 'images',
];

dpm($this->image_deltas);

for ($i=0;$i<=$this->image_deltas;$i++) {
  $form['images'][$i]['image'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Image Path:'),
  ];
}

$form['add_another'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Add Another Image'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'addAnotherImage'],
    'wrapper' => 'images',
  ],
  '#submit' => [$this, 'addAnotherImageSubmit'],
  '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
];
```

The form submission handler is the following.

```php
public function addAnotherImageSubmit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->image_deltas++;
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

The AJAX callback is the following one.

```php
public function addAnotherImage(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['images'];
}
```

When I submit the form, `dpm()` prints *0* every time. The same thing happens if I use `$form_state->set('image_deltas')` and `$form_state->get('image_deltas')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
'#submit' => [$this, 'addAnotherImageSubmit'],
```

Should be this:

```
'#submit' => [[$this, 'addAnotherImageSubmit']],
```

Submit handlers are only called for #type `submit` and not #type `button`, so you'll need to change the type.

You will also need to use $form_state->set(), rather than a property on the class. This is because the form class is re-instantiated for each iteration (build, validate, submit), and therefore values stored in the properties of the form class will not persist. $form_state->set() persists values, as these are stored in the database, and are repopulated for each instance of the form class (as long as you call $form_state->setRebuild() as you have done).

Comment: Changing it to that has no difference. The form submits, and prints out the $this->image_deltas; as 0 still (which is default), instead of incrementing it like it should.

Comment: That's because the form class is re-instantiated for each iteration (build, validate, submit), and therefore values stored in the properties of the form class will not persist. You will need to use $form_state->set() to persist values, as these are stored in the database, and are repopulated for each instance of the form class.

Comment: As stated in the original question, I did that originally, and it was still not working as it's supposed to. $form_state->set() does not appear to persist across an ajax callback/request as I can set it inside of the submit/validate handler, and try to dump it into the form after ajax callback has ran, and the value returns empty.

Comment: It wouldn't work when you tried it earlier, as you had your submit handler declared incorrectly. You need to do both - declare your submit handler correctly, and use $form_state->set(). You didn't have your submit handler declared correctly, meaning your submit handler would not have been called, meaning $form_state->set() would never been called.

Comment: What I meant, was just like before, after changing how the handler is defined in the form, it still doesn't save to form state. It was the next thing I tried after the first way didn't work. 

I have the $form_state->set('image_deltas') declaration inside of the addAnotherImageSubmit() handler, and am printing it out to the form and it's returning empty.

Comment: You need to show your current code, not describe it. Update your original post with your current code that is not working, where the submit handler has been fixed, and you are using $form_state->set().

Comment: I just updated the original question to match the pastebin and removed the comment.

Comment: Submit handlers are not called for #type `button`. You need to change the type to `submit`.

Comment: Wow, that solved it. What is the purpose of having a button type of 'button' if you can't do anything with it? Generally a button would be used to trigger an action, which would be a form submit.

Comment: You're welcome...

Comment: How do I mark a comment as an answer? All I can seem to do is upvote them (which I did already) Oh, nevermind, I see you changed your answer to include the correct one. Marking it now. Thanks!

Comment: An element of #type `button` can be used for front-end JavaScript actions that don't do anything on the server (or have custom AJAX applied bypassing the #ajax API). An element of #type 'submit' wouldn't be as good a fit. Also, as both element types exist in HTML, Drupal provides a method for them, even if Drupal's own APIs gear towards using a 'submit' button.